# Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data fromJson

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring

I have stuck on this error. I checked other similar problems as well. I have a simple angularjs/spring application. The request gives a 200 but I am receiving a JSON parse exception in the developer tools/firebug for the response. The response from the server is a simple String which I am able to see. I suspect the problem is that angular is parsing it as JSON. Please help me with this.

Angular controller:

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp',[]);
loginApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.login = function(isValid) {
      if(isValid){
          var formData= {"username":$scope.username,"password":$scope.password};
          $http.post('/suite/rest/dologin',formData).success(function(response){
              console.log(response);
              alert(response);
          });
      }
  };
}]);
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String doLogin(@RequestBody final User user) {

    String validateUser = "admin";

    return validateUser;
}
```

Error msg:

```
Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
fromJson@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:1352:9
defaultHttpResponseTransform@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:10455:1
transformData/<@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:10546:12
forEach@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:322:11
transformData@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:10545:3
transformResponse@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:11343:21
processQueue@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:16104:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:16120:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:17378:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:17191:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:17486:13
done@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:11637:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:11843:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8080/suite/extResources/Angular/angular.js:11776:1
```

[image]

[image]

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty
    private String password;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

Comment: And what exactly does that "simple string" look like? Oh wait, I see it. Well the text `admin` is definitely not valid JSON. A plain string value must be quoted with double-quotes.

Comment: Please post both JSON data and User class

Comment: validateUser = "admin"; is String, not json object.

Comment: validateUser = "{\"name\":\"admin\"}"; maybe works

Comment: I looks like the content type for the response is `application/json`. You should switch that to `text/plain`. See the docs for [Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers).

Comment: @Pointy : I meant my String class returns String not JSON data..

Comment: @CristianMeneses : I posted the User class. I am giving data {"username":"admin","password":"admin"} and expecting a String response from Spring which is admin.

Comment: @AliTorabi : Can't be the response data type be a String?

Comment: Try: @RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET)
@ResponseBody
public String foo() {
    return "Response!";
}

Comment: @4castle: Doesn't Http header set the type for request? My request is JSON, the problem is my output which is String. How to change the content type for response?

Comment: Problem is on your Spring side. checkout how spring returns string header post type

Comment: @AliTorabi: Spot On! I made my Spring controller to `@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")`..It works now! :)

Comment: Thanks guys for all you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the response type explicitly using the [`config` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) in the request. This will override the processing being assumed by the `Content-Type` that is in the response's header.

```
$http.post('/suite/rest/dologin',formData,{responseType:'text'})
```

Ultimately the solution though is to change your server-side so that it doesn't return a response with `Content-Type: application/json` in the header.

Comment: I set some similar to this on @Ali's suggestion...I changed my controller to this: `@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")` and was able to make this work..Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

String `admin` is not a valid `json`, so parsing it throws an error

Try returning something like:

```
String validateUser = {"id": "admin"}
```

Comment: I also thought on similar line but is there no way to simply read a String response in angular?

Comment: Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, section **Setting HTTP Headers**

Comment: I already checked this out...doesn't header does the changes for request only not response?